# How can I copy value in a struct that is passed by reference to the function and member A is also a pointer?

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures

I am learning the pointer and I stuck on an issue as I cannot debug the program because it gives me address rather than the actual array.

I am trying to create an Abstract datatype of Array

```
struct ARRAY_ADT
{
    int *A; // For storing the pointer to base address of the array
    int size; //For storing the size of the array
    int len; //For storing the length of the array
};
```

Now to insert a number in it's correct index I had written a function called **Insert**. I am calling it from main.

It's look like this

```
void insert(struct ARRAY_ADT *Array)
{
    int num;
    int index;
    int i = Array -> len - 1;

    printf("Enter the value to be inserted: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("Enter the value to be index: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    printf("Array length:%d \n", Array ->len);


    if(OutofRange(Array -> size, Array -> len))
    {
        printf("Array is full:");
    }
    else
    {
        if (OutofRange(Array -> size, index))
        {
            printf("Index is not valid");
        }
        else
        {
            //int *temp = NULL;

            while(i >= index)
            {
                Array->(A+i+1) = Array->(A+i); // Problem
                i--;
            }
           
            Array -> A[index] = num;
            Array -> len++;
        }

    }
}
```

So, how can I copy value from right to left to make place for the new number.

**How can I copy value in a struct that is passed by reference to the function and member A is also a pointer?**

I just want to perform this operation

```
Array.A[i++] = Array.A[i];
```

Comment: Use `Array->A[i+1] = Array->A[i];`

Comment: You can also call `memmove()`.

Comment: Why not simply use the dynamic array idiom?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate what is the dynamic array idiom?

Comment: C is not C++ and C++ is not C. Please only tag the language you are actually using. Looks like C

Comment: `A[i++] = A[i];` is pretty much the same as `A[i] = A[i]; i++;` which is pretty much the same as `i++;`.

Comment: what is the problem? `Array.A[i++] = Array.A[i];` or `Array->(A+i+1) = Array->(A+i);`?

Comment: obviously you do know the correct syntax at `Array -> A[index] = num;`? (despite the (imho) weird spacing)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 See https://gist.github.com/euppal/b473150426252dff15dc032ff5858ef3

Comment: and `int*`  should be initialized , doubt you do so

Comment: @IanAbbott `A[i++] = A[i]` causes undefined behavior because it modifies and reads `i` between sequence points. Also, they don't want to increment `i`, because they're decrementing it on the next line.

Comment: @appleapple `Array->(A+i+1) = Array->(A+i)` is plain wrong stuff. see answer

Comment: Thanks @Barmar it totally worked. Well I know C and C++ are different in many aspect but they both use pointer that's why I added that. However, I removed the C++ tag. I want to understand in depth why A[i++] didn't worked. Thank you everyone for all the replies.

Comment: @Barmar `A[i++] = A[i]` just does nothing . it's not ub unless out of bounds

Comment: Thank you everyone for quick reply. Hope you all have a great day. I want to learn why A[i++] didn't work when I tried that in detail. It works in normal array but not in this. just why @appleapple.

Comment: `++i` will work. i mean `k[++i] = k[i - 1]`.  `i++` will work also  `k[i++ + 1] = k[i]`

Comment: mistake. `k[++i] = k[i]` is right

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @Barmar yeah. see c++11 section https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183735/7172363

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Well I ask OP what is the question, I never imply it (OP's code) is  correct (and in fact my [next comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813580/how-can-i-copy-value-in-a-struct-that-is-passed-by-reference-to-the-function-and?noredirect=1#comment116363754_65813580) say it's not)

Comment: @appleapple so you just told him that correct syntax of pointer notation is an array noration. correct syntax of `Array->(A+i+1) = Array->(A+i);`  is `*(Array->A + i + 1) = *(Array->A + i)` .

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин they are the same.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин can you explicitly point out which sentence I said was wrong? Not sure what you're arguing.

Comment: @appleapple you'd offered him line of code that you said  is wrong and to let him know this you'd then offered him to change notation. is it right or wrong haha ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array->A[i+1] = Array->A[i]`. Or you can shift without a loop by using `memmove()`

```
memmove(&(Array->A[i+1]), &(Array->A[i]), sizeof(Array->A[i]) * (Array->len - index));
```

Answer (score -1):

right is

```
struct xntype
{
  int *b;
} xn;
*(xn.b + 1) = 15;
```